# UTF-8 source files are not supported in avisynth

Tags: unicode, utf-8, ffmpeg, directshow, avisynth

I use avisynth to demux video from audio.
When I use

```
 x = "m.mkv"
 ffvideosource(x)
```

It work correctly but when I change my video filename to a UTF-8 one and my script as:

```
 x = "م.mkv"
 ffvideosource(x)
```

I Got the following error:
     failed to open for hashing avisynth

I found a link ([UTF-8 source files are not supported](http://www.animemusicvideos.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=104105)) who tell UTF-8 file name not work in avisynth, and to correct the problem, it said:

> specify the parameter utf8=true when calling ffvideosource, save the script as UTF-8 without BOM and then see if that works.

But, I couldn't solve the problem. As I Open the script in the notepad and save it in utf-8 format, I got the following error:

> UTF-8 Source files are not supported, re-save script with ANSI encoding

How can I solve the problem, How can I run my script with a UTF-8 filename?

Comment: Did you try with the parameter `utf8=true` when calling `ffvideosource`?

Comment: Yes, I used it as:
`ffvideosource(x,utf8=true)`
and it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very common problem when using UTF-8 in AviSynth.

Follow these steps:

1. Check the plugins folder. There should exist these three files: `ffms2.dll`, `ffmsindex.exe`, and `FFMS2.avsi`. If you did not have problem with `ANSI`, I guess that you don't have `FFMS2.avsi` in your plugins folder; In this situation download the latest version form [here](https://github.com/FFMS/ffms2/releases).
2. After that make an `AVS` file with Notepad++. For example I do this:

   ```
   x = "C:/Users/Nemat/Desktop/StackOverFlow/نعمت.mkv"
   ffmpegsource2(x,utf8=true)
   ```

   Please note that here I used `ffmpegsource2()`.
3. In the `Encoding` menu from Notepadd++ select `Encode in UTF-8 without BOM`.
4. Save your file.
5. Check the video file exists in the addressed directory.
6. Double click on your `AVS` file.
7. Enjoy it!

Answer (score 3):

“Withoutt BOM” is important. You need to save the file as raw UTF-8 without the Microsoft-style faux-BOM. Notepad can't do this, it always saves UTF-8 files with that generally-undesirable `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF` header. Most other text editors (e.g. Notepad++) can do it properly.

AviSynth isn't really Unicode-aware so it doesn't want you using UTF-8 and will give that error message to try to stop you making mistakes. `ffvideosource`'s workaround of hiding UTF-8 bytes in what AviSynth sees as ‘ANSI’ characters only works as long as AviSynth sees the file as ANSI. AviSynth  doesn't have very sophisticated encoding-guessing, so removing the faux-BOM is enough to convince it is dealing with ANSI.